How to populate for all fields with union all
I have two CTE's with different data that needs to be union together. The issue that I am having is try to get all the fields to populate with all the data from both CTE's. One CTE has one row of data.
with software_production as (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        f.client_id,
        m.firmware,
        f.created_at,
        --f.packing_date same as first configuration_change_timestamp
    FROM `production-us`.`dev_warehouse`.`dev_dataset` AS f , UNNEST(motion_trackers) AS m
    WHERE f.client_id IS NOT NULL
        and f.client_id = 'US-211111'
        AND f.client_id != '-2'
),
next_created_at AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        LEAD(created_at)
            OVER (PARTITION BY client_id  ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS created_at_lead
    FROM software_production
),
next_created_at_final AS (
    SELECT
        * EXCEPT(created_at_lead),
        CASE
            WHEN created_at_lead IS NULL
            THEN TIMESTAMP('9999-12-31 00:00:00')
            ELSE created_at_lead
        END AS created_at_lead
    FROM next_created_at
    WHERE created_at_lead IS NULL
        OR (created_at != created_at_lead)
)
select * from next_created_at_final

The data looks like this:
client_id       |firmware|created_at             |created_at_lead        |
----------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
US-211111       |4.3.1   |2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|9999-12-30 19:00:00.000|

The second part of the code for what I'm doing a union on looks like:
with first_dt_versions as (
    select
        client_id,
        system_created_at       as created_at,
        device.dt_semantic_version      as device_dt_version,
        configuration_change_timestamp --first date matched the packing_date
    from `production-us`.`dev_warehouse`.`dev_client_system`
    where device.dt_semantic_version is not null
    and client_id = 'US-211111' 
),
dt_conversion as (
    select distinct
        client_id,
        created_at,
        device_dt_version,
        configuration_change_timestamp                   as dt_version_configuration_start_date,
        lead(configuration_change_timestamp)
            over(PARTITION BY client_id  
            ORDER BY configuration_change_timestamp ASC) as dt_version_configuration_end_date,
    from first_dt_versions 
    group by
        client_id,  
        created_at,
        device_dt_version,
        configuration_change_timestamp
)
select * from dt_conversion

The returned data looks like such:
client_id|created_at             |device_dt_version|dt_version_configuration_start_date|dt_version_configuration_end_date|
---------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
US-211111|2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|2.16.4           |            2024-02-06 05:09:58.000|          2024-02-07 05:42:31.000|
US-211111|2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|2.17.1           |            2024-03-13 04:49:18.000|          2024-03-15 18:01:00.000|
US-211111|2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|2.18.1           |            2024-03-29 17:34:48.000|          2024-03-30 13:03:31.000|
US-211111|2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|2.17.1           |            2024-02-26 05:23:34.000|          2024-02-28 17:36:46.000|
US-211111|2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|2.16.4           |            2024-02-09 05:57:00.000|          2024-02-13 18:46:01.000|
US-211111|2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|2.17.0           |            2024-02-17 09:01:29.000|          2024-02-17 09:01:29.000|

When I union both sets of data I get the following results:
client_id|device_dt_version|firmware|dt_version_configuration_start_date|dt_version_configuration_end_date|
----------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
US-211111       |                 |4.3.1   |                                   |                                 |
US-211111       |2.9.1            |        |            2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|          2024-01-17 17:46:13.000|
US-211111       |2.13.2           |        |            2024-01-17 17:46:13.000|          2024-01-18 04:57:31.000|
US-211111       |2.16.2           |        |            2024-01-18 04:57:31.000|          2024-01-18 04:57:31.000|
US-211111       |2.13.2           |        |            2024-01-18 04:57:31.000|          2024-01-19 04:39:40.000|

What I'm expecting is:
client_id|device_dt_version|firmware|dt_version_configuration_start_date|dt_version_configuration_end_date|
---------+-----------------+--------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
US-211111|2.9.1            |4.3.1   |            2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|          2024-01-17 17:46:13.000|
US-211111|2.9.1            |4.3.1   |            2023-11-22 11:21:10.000|          2024-01-17 17:46:13.000|
US-211111|2.13.2           |4.3.1   |            2024-01-17 17:46:13.000|          2024-01-18 04:57:31.000|
US-211111|2.16.2           |4.3.1   |            2024-01-18 04:57:31.000|          2024-01-18 04:57:31.000|
US-211111|2.13.2           |4.3.1   |            2024-01-18 04:57:31.000|          2024-01-19 04:39:40.000|

I tried doing a join with the packing_date and configuration_change_timestamp because the packing_date and the first configuration_change_timestamp match along with the client_id and then doing a union but that still gave me the same results.
Any help would be appreciated!

You might need to provide examples records with multiple client and firmware combinations for us to fully understand your scenario.

You should do a join on Client_id instead of a Union. Your expected results contains 5 rows with the first row duplicated. I suspect you actually want 4 rows returned with no duplicated rows.
SELECT c.client_id, 
       c.device_dt_version,
       f.firmware,
       c.dt_version_configuration_start_date,
       c.dt_version_configuration_end_date
FROM dt_conversion c
INNER JOIN next_created_at_final  f ON c.Client_id =fClient_id 




client_id
device_dt_version
firmware
dt_version_configuration_start_date
dt_version_configuration_end_date




US-211111
2.9.1
4.3.1
2023-11-22 11:21:10.000
2024-01-17 17:46:13.000


US-211111
2.13.2
4.3.1
2024-01-17 17:46:13.000
2024-01-18 04:57:31.000


US-211111
2.16.2
4.3.1
2024-01-18 04:57:31.000
2024-01-18 04:57:31.000


US-211111
2.13.2
4.3.1
2024-01-18 04:57:31.000
2024-01-19 04:39:40.000




Hey, I'll give this a shot with a couple of other samples and let you know if it's the desired outcome
